# C/C++ Preprocessor - 'Charify'

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Is there a way of 'charify'ing something using the C/C++ preprocessor? You can 'stringify' by doing:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
```

So, would there be a way of 'charify'ing using the same principles?

Comment: `(#x [0])`? (length)

Comment: At least GCC and probably Clang treat `("string literal"[0])` as a constant expression.

Comment: @user3175411 but unfortunately C does not treat it as a constant expression

Comment: @ouah, are you sure? It looks quite constant to me. Chapter and verse of the standard, please?

Comment: @vonbrand try to compile `static int x = "a"[0];` with gcc or clang and you'll see you get an error for non constant initializer. For the standard look in c99 at 6.6p6 and 6.6p7, and you'll see "a"[0] is not in the allowed list of constant expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
#define CHARa() 'a'
#define CHARb() 'b'
#define CHARc() 'c'
// ...
#define CHARIFY(x) CHAR ## x()

CHARIFY(a)
```

Comment: If you think this is ugly, think about what you need for operators. `CHARIFY(%)` must expand to something like `PREFIX % SUFFIX` without token concatenation (as % can't be part of a token). Yet the token sequence `PREFIX a SUFFIX` (again without concatenation) must also be valid and a constant expression.